# iPhone programming: Inserting labels between sentences

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have an interesting UI where a table view contains some lines of text. There are certain words in each line that I need to highlight and those words can be selected to render some tooltip.

I thought of using labels for these words so I can highlight them and also capture any touch events. But I couldn't find a way of achieving a flow layout.

Is there a better approach to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So I found an alternate way of doing this by using the Three20 project :http://wiki.github.com/facebook/three20/

Check out the TTCatalog sample application. This includes applying different styles to text and creating hyperlinks (see Styled labels).

Answer (score 0):

A UIWebView would certainly handle the layout problem, but may cause other performance issues, especially if you're putting it in a table view.

You might also look at the `NSString (UIStringDrawing)` methods, which are helpful for measuring and drawing text.  They're quite powerful actually, allowing you to specify size constraints and line break modes.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. Is there a sample app that I can refer to?

Comment: @Mansi, sorry, none that I'm aware of